# In a basic project, as soon as I move I am teleported below my landscape. What is going on?

Tags: unreal-engine5

I created a blank template and added a landscape.

When I simulate the project, I can look around with the mouse, but as soon as I move with WASD, I am instantly below the landscape. It doesn't fall, so it doesn't appear to be a gravity-related issue, I'm just down there all of a sudden.

Does anyone have any idea what I could have done wrong?

I've not altered any blueprints as far as I'm aware.

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**

Answer (score 0):

Without watching the code is hard to understand what is wrong,but check this:

- In the code/blueprint check that when you press input the position is correctly Set (should be like current position + offset based on direction)
- Check if your input event is used somewhere else (maybe some uknown behaviour is executed)

Comment: Without code, the question is unanswerable and will be closed.

Comment: Fair enough. My apologies, I am very new to this.

Answer (score 0):

I am a numpty. I didn't realise I was working on a map where I'd added a sphere as my sky box, and the collision was turned on, so any movement instantly jumped me down below the bounds of the sphere. Thanks.